# Configuration of Twig via FTP with Autoloader.php

Tags: php, html, ftp, twig

I try to get Twig to work in my application.

So, I've unpacked and uploaded Twig files on FTP in `Twig` folder.

I've created in `twig_templates` folder template `base.twig` looking like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="pl">
    <head>
        <title>{{title}}</title>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="content-container">        
            <{{type}} id="content">         
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
            </{{type}}>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

And I've tried to use this template in `base.php` file (deployed in the project root folder):

```
 <?php     

require_once '/Twig/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('/twig_templates');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => '/twig_templates/cache') );


$template = $twig->loadTemplate('base.twig');
echo $template->render(array (title=>"title", type=>"article"));

?>
```

I'm completely unable to get this to work and have no idea why. I've tried with both `.twig` and `.html` files but it doesn't seem making any difference. Code seems fine (to me), so maybe it's all about Twig configuration?

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: Well I haven't noticed any error logs so far and I'm not sure how to get one : / Could you please explain how to get server errors with Netbeans 8.0 connecting via FTP? (Only messages I get are related to correct FTP connection.)